# Extjs beforerender to set async-obtained variable

Tags: asynchronous, extjs

My ExtJS application displays certain UI elements depending on a boolean variable.

This boolean variable, however, is the result of calling an async function. As a result, the boolean is set to a Promise that is fulfilled, rather than true or false proper. This affects whether the UI elements are actually displayed (a Promise is not exactly a boolean, after all).

The code looks like this:

```js
Ext.define('userDefinedComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    requires: ['someHelperFile'],
    

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
        var enabled = someHelperFile.someAsyncFunc() // enabled is a boolean that is returned as fulfilled Promise instead

        Ext.apply(me, {
            // layout and padding
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'internallyDefinedForm',
                    fieldConfigs: {
                        // other fields
                        'someFormField': {
                            hidden: !enabled, // depends on enabled
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    xtype: 'internallyDefinedGrid',
                    columnConfigs: {
                        // other columns
                        'someColumn': {
                            hidden: !enabled, // deends on enabled
                        }
                    },
                    
                }
            ]
        })
    }
})
```

I want the field `enabled` to really be a boolean rather than a Promise. In other words, I want to wait for the `someAsyncFunc` to run the result, before setting `hidden` property of the `internallyDefinedForm` and `internallyDefinedGrid`.

What are my possibilities? I was thinking of using a `beforerender`, like below:

```js
Ext.define('userDefinedComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    requires: ['someHelperFile'],
    

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            // layout and padding
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'internallyDefinedForm',
                    fieldConfigs: {
                        // other fields
                        'someFormField': {
                            hidden: !me.enabled, // depends on enabled
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    xtype: 'internallyDefinedGrid',
                    columnConfigs: {
                        // other columns
                        'someColumn': {
                            hidden: !me.enabled, // deends on enabled
                        }
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        beforerender: function() { // this is the beforerender
                            me.enabled = someHelperFile.someAsyncFunc();
                            console.log("beforerender triggered in grid");
                        }
                    },
                    
                }
            ]
        })
    }
})
```

And in fact, using the `beforerender` for the `internallyDefinedGrid` only, I can see the text "beforerender triggered in grid" triggered very early. However, the fact remains that the behavior that I observe does not correspond to what I expect: although the async `someAsyncFunc` should return `true` based on the API response it gets, such that `me.enabled` is true, the actual UI associated with the `internallyDefinedGrid` behaves as if `me.enabled` is false instead. I observe that the column on the UI is hidden, and this is only possible when `me.enabled` is false, such that the column `someColumn` does not appear on the grid. After all, the `hidden` field of `someColumn` is set to `!enabled`.

I am confident that the UI for the grid behaves not like what I expect it to, so there is a problem with the async behavior. But I'm really lost as to how to set the asynchronously obtained `enabled` or `me.enabled` field adequately.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a View Model and binding, as explained [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html).

Basically you define what your UI is depending on, under the **data** tag in the View Model (you can set the initial value here):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.TestViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    data: {
        something: false,
    },
}
```

Then you bind the visibility to this value in the view:

```
bind: {
    hidden: '{something}'
}
```

or

```
bind: {
    hidden: '{!something}'
}
```

You fetch the async data, and once you have the result, set the value in the View Model (**this** can be either the view or the controller):

```
this.getViewModel().set('something', RESULT_OF_ASYNC)
```

With binding ExtJS takes care of refreshing the visibility of your component every time when the value in the View Model is changed. There are good examples at the link I provided. This is a very powerful and complex feature of ExtJS, worth learning.